# How to get the response over HTTP

Tags: c#, http, http-post, httprequest, httpresponse

I am sending HTTP request. I need to save the HTTP response to that request.

This is the request URL : `http://notify.test.com/gateway.do?service=notify_verify&partner=2088&notify_id=abcdefghijklmnopqrst`

Code I tried is below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://notify.test.com/gateway.do?service=notify_verify&partner=2088&notify_id=abcdefghijklmnopqrst");
        request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
        request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

The response will be True or False. how can I save that?

Comment: It is not a good idea to include API keys in your question since this is a public website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirements are simple, `WebClient` goes a long way:

```
string result;
using(var client = new WebClient()) {
    client.Proxy = ...
    result = client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

See also: `DownloadData` etc.

Comment: When I use your code block in aspx page, the result was 'False' or 'True'. But when I try to send request from a custom Http handler with passing values to 'partner' and 'notify_id' from database, the result is a XML- `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>
<api><is_success>F</is_success><error>message</error></api>`. Why this so strange? And I want the status, ofcourse `<is_success>` value. So the `result` contains a xml. I wrote `XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(result));`. How to read `<is_success>` value from xml reader?

Comment: @Sandy easiest way would be to load into a DOM. XmlDocument maybe

Answer (score 1):

You acquire a `System.IO.Stream` from `GetResponseStream()`, the `Stream` offers you the `Read` method you can read on

```
using(Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream()){ //release Stream after use
    if(resStream.CanRead){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[resStream.Length]; // or whatever
        if(resStream.Read(buffer, 0, resStream.Length) == 0) 
        {
            // end of Stream
        }
        else{
             //data received, work on buffer
        }
    }
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) for `System.IO.Stream`.

Comment: That is very bad `Read` code; you haven't checked the return value from `Read`, nor have you looped to read multiple buffers, based on either the end of the stream or the content-length header. This demonstrates bad practice IMO.

Comment: For this particular case it is sufficient as the OP only expects "True" or "False".

Comment: the funny thing about http is that you need to cope with more things than you expect... but even so: there is still nothing in TCP that says you're going to get all of "True" or "False" in a single packet.

Comment: Okay, but this is up to the coder then, the OP will need to determine this then

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var resStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(resStream))
{
    var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```